# DEoptim stack imbalance problems

Tags: r, optimization

When running the following optimization task (R v.3.0.2)

```
library(DEoptim)

x <- seq(-6,6,length=100); y <- tanh(x)
goal <- function(par) return(1-abs(cor(x*par,y,method='spearman')))

ctrl <- DEoptim::DEoptim.control(VTR=0, trace=FALSE)

res <- DEoptim::DEoptim(goal,lower=-1,upper=1, ctrl)
```

I get stack imbalance warnings

```
Warning: stack imbalance in '<-', 14 then 13
Warning: stack imbalance in 'withVisible', 7 then 6
```

and `unprotect()` errors. If `VTR` is set below 0 (i.e. to a value impossible to obtain) then the problem disappears, but I'd rather not do that due to performance issues.

The result gets returned despite the errors however I fear it might be unstable/incorrect. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a problem in the C code, not something you can fix.  But it's something I can fix, and it's fixed as of revision 116 on R-Forge.  Here's the patch:

```
Index: DEoptim/src/de4_0.c
===================================================================
--- DEoptim/src/de4_0.c (revision 115)
+++ DEoptim/src/de4_0.c (working copy)
@@ -423,7 +423,6 @@

     /*------Trial mutation now in t_tmpP-----------------*/
     /* evaluate mutated population */
-    if(i_iter > 1) UNPROTECT(1);  // previous iteration's sexp_t_tmpC
     PROTECT(sexp_map_pop = popEvaluate(l_nfeval, sexp_t_tmpP,  fnMap, rho, 0));
     memmove(REAL(sexp_t_tmpP), REAL(sexp_map_pop), i_NP * i_D * sizeof(double));
     UNPROTECT(1);  // sexp_map_pop
@@ -458,6 +457,7 @@

       }
     } /* End mutation loop through ensemble */
+    UNPROTECT(1);  // sexp_t_tmpC

     if (d_c > 0) { /* calculate new meanCR and meanF */
       meanCR = (1-d_c)*meanCR + d_c*goodCR;
@@ -555,7 +555,7 @@
   *gt_bestC = t_bestC;

   PutRNGstate();
-  UNPROTECT(P+1); // +1 is for last iteration's sexp_t_tmpC
+  UNPROTECT(P);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using revision 118 and I had a similar problem:

```
Warning: stack imbalance in '.Call', 13 then 12
Warning: stack imbalance in '<-', 11 then 10
```

That happened when I inverted the sign of the variable that the objective function returns, from `return(-var)` to `return(var)`. The way around it was just to change the sign in the code before.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10440963)

Comment: @Trilarion "The way around it was just to change the sign in the code before." is not an answer?

Comment: @JiriTousek Is it the answer to the question?

Comment: @Trilarion I'm not R expert so I don't know if it's a correct answer, but it seems to me as *an* answer. I could be wrong though.

Comment: If you are unsure, then please post it as a comment as it will let users verify and then you can add as an answer.